# Unknown cause of javafx.fxml.LoadException

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I have a three stages JavaFX app (right now only the login/register/blank view) and I tried to communicate between them. I've created a super class and all stages extend that super class.
Now, when I run the main class like below, I get the runtime errors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    conn = DBUtils.connectToDB(DB_SCHEMA);
    new LoginController(primaryStage);
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Mihai/Faculta/Anul%203/Licenta/Aplicatie/licenta-mihai-laza/out/production/licenta-mihai-laza/application/login.fxml:7

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at licenta.mihai.laza/application.superclasses.StageSuperclass.<init>(StageSuperclass.java:20)
at licenta.mihai.laza/application.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:45)
at licenta.mihai.laza/application.Main.start(Main.java:21)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: application.LoginController
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: application.LoginController.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    ... 25 more
[INFO] Connection to database closed
Exception running application application.Main
```

**StageSuperclass.java:**

```
public class StageSuperclass extends Stage {
// Frame window
private Stage stage;
private double xOffset = 0;
private double yOffset = 0;

public StageSuperclass(Stage stage, String fxmlFilePath) throws java.io.IOException {
    this.stage = stage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFilePath));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
    this.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        }
    });
    this.setScene(scene);
    this.show();
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return this.stage;
}
```

**LoginController.java:**

```
public class LoginController extends StageSuperclass {
// Constants
private static final String LOGIN_FXML_PATH = "/application/login.fxml";
private static final String WRONG_CREDENTIALS_MSG = "Datele de logare sunt gresite!";
private static final String BLANK_CREDENTIALS_MSG = "Introduceti username si parola!";

// PageObjects
RegisterController registerPage;

// FXML Objects
@FXML
private Button btnLogin;
@FXML
private Button btnIesire;
@FXML
private TextField tfdUsername;
@FXML
private TextField tfdParola;
@FXML
private Label lblInvalid;
@FXML
private Hyperlink lnkInregistrare;

// Constructor
public LoginController(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    super(stage, LOGIN_FXML_PATH);
}

public void inregistrareLinkOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    new RegisterController(this.getStage());
}

public void loginButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (!tfdUsername.getText().isBlank() && !tfdParola.getText().isBlank()) {
        if (validareLogin()) {
            new MainWindowController(this.getStage());
        }
    } else {
        lblInvalid.setText(BLANK_CREDENTIALS_MSG);
    }
}

public void iesireButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnIesire.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}

private boolean validareLogin() {
    List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(COL_USERNAME, COL_PAROLA);
    List<String> whereValues = Arrays.asList(tfdUsername.getText(), tfdParola.getText());
    if (DBUtils.select(columns, columns, whereValues, DBUtils.TABEL_UTILIZATORI.TABLE_NAME, Main.conn).size() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        lblInvalid.setText(WRONG_CREDENTIALS_MSG);
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**login.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LoginController">
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0084b8;">
        <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutY="17.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="300.0"
                   text="LOGIN" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
                <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
    <Button id="btnLogin" fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="216.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#loginButtonOnAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="233.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0084b8;"
            text="Login" textFill="WHITE">
        <font>
            <Font size="13.0"/>
        </font>
    </Button>
    <TextField id="tfdUsername" fx:id="tfdUsername" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="82.0" promptText="User">
        <font>
            <Font size="14.0"/>
        </font>
    </TextField>
    <PasswordField id="tfdParola" fx:id="tfdParola" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="123.0" promptText="Parola">
        <font>
            <Font size="14.0"/>
        </font>
    </PasswordField>
    <Hyperlink id="lnkInregistrare" fx:id="lnkInregistrare" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="153.0"
               onAction="#inregistrareLinkOnAction" text="Nu ai cont? Inregistreaza-te!">
        <font>
            <Font size="11.0"/>
        </font>
    </Hyperlink>
    <Label layoutX="33.0" layoutY="87.0" text="User">
        <font>
            <Font size="14.0"/>
        </font>
    </Label>
    <Label layoutX="32.0" layoutY="128.0" text="Parola">
        <font>
            <Font size="14.0"/>
        </font>
    </Label>
    <Button id="btnCancel" fx:id="btnIesire" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="254.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#iesireButtonOnAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="233.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0084b8;"
            text="Iesire" textFill="WHITE">
        <font>
            <Font size="13.0"/>
        </font>
    </Button>
    <Label id="lblInvalid" fx:id="lblInvalid" alignment="TOP_CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="44.0"
           layoutY="194.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="233.0" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="RED">
        <font>
            <Font size="11.0"/>
        </font>
    </Label>
</AnchorPane>
```

Do you have any suggestions solving this exception?

Comment: The stack trace is pretty clear. The problem is that you are loading an FXML file which specifies a controller class that doesn't have a no-argument constructor. If you want to instantiate a controller class directly (in code) and have it load the FXML, use the [Custom Component Pattern](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)

Comment: So, @James_D you are telling me that the approach of StageSuperclass constructor <public StageSuperclass(Stage stage, String fxmlFilePath)> isn't good? It's my first JavaFX project and I am a newbie ... I need that stage and the path to the file to instantiate another stages during runtime ...
Is my understanding correct? If so, can you help me with an alternative approach of mine?

Comment: @James_D I've added some blank constructors there, and now the app is running, but when I attempt to drag and move it, I get NullPointerExceptions, targeting this part of code here:
root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
..
stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
..
}
I assume stage is causing the NPE. Do you have any suggestion to make that drag and move code work?

Comment: The actual problem is that `LoginController` doesn't have a no-argument constructor. But it's really unclear why you are subclassing `Stage` or why you have an inheritance hierarchy for your controllers. If this is your first time using JavaFX, why not use the same approach as in any of the basic examples? I.e. don't instantiate the controller (the `FXMLLoader` does that for you), just load the FXML directly, place the result in a `Scene` and the `Scene` in a stage.

Comment: You don't need to subclass `Stage` or pass the `Stage` around. You can get a reference to the `Stage` in your event handler with, e.g. `Window stage = root.getScene().getWindow();`.

Comment: I am trying to build an app with multiple stages and all of them should be without that default system minimize/close buttons and I need all those Stages to have that .setOnMouseDragged event there so I can move the app on the screen. And I thought that would be a good approach, instead of reusing that code everywhere in every screen.

Comment: Why not just put that code in a separate class, and use it from each of the controllers that need it? Don't overuse or abuse inheritance. This is not what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused because your FXML file specifies `fx:controller="application.LoginController"`. This will cause the `FXMLLoader` to create an instance of `application.LoginController` by (effectively) calling its no-argument constructor. However, your `LoginController` class doesn't have a no-argument constructor: hence the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: application.LoginController.<init>()
```

The typical approach is to load the FXML file, and let the `FXMLLoader` create the controller for you. Except in quite advanced usage, you should not instantiate the controller class yourself, because the `FXMLLoader` does that for you.

Get rid of the inheritance in `LoginController` (i.e. it doesn't need to be a subclass of your other controller class, and certainly should not be a subclass of `Stage`). Then just do

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private double xOffset = 0 ;
    private double yOffset = 0 ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(LOGIN_FXML_PATH));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        root.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        });
    
        root.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent ->  {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If you need to reuse the same functionality repeatedly, just create a separate class in the normal way:

```
public class StageDragHandler {

    private double xOffset = 0 ;
    private double yOffset = 0 ;

    public Stage createStage(Parent root) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        configureStage(root, stage);
        return stage ;
    }

    public void configureStage(Parent root, Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        root.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        });
    
        root.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });
    }
}
```

Then your application class reduces to:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(LOGIN_FXML_PATH));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        new StageDragHandler().configureStage(root, primaryStage);   
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and you can use similar code anywhere you need it.

Comment: I've done that, removed that inheritance and now it works pretty good, with multiple stages. But there's a weird movement of the Stage when I drag it with the mouse. Please see it in the imgur album: https://imgur.com/a/0sYLxen
Do you have any suggestion or do you know the cause of that movement of all Stages to the start of the screen when I drag them?

Comment: @mihailaza I had `getSceneX()` (and Y) in the drag handler, instead of `getScreenX()`. Should work smoothly with the fix.

Comment: My bad there, I don't know how that slipped there :)). Thank you a lot! Have nice day!